# Sq Lite Database Table upgrade

Tags: sqlite

I am creating an app it takes data from the server and storing it in SQLite database but each time I run the app the data gets append in the database. I tried `onUpgrade()` method to drop table and create a new one, but its not working because `db_version` is the same. But if I change the version manually then its working... but I want solution so that my version changes each time automatically when I run the app....

OR if there is an another alternative please share it....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably didn't understand what is database `Upgrade`. In two words you upgrade the version of your database when your DB **model** changed, not the data!
To clear your database for testing purposes use sqlite `DROP TABLE` or physically delete the file!
If you upgrade the version of the database each time your app starts - you will lose all the database data each time your app starts, so why do you need the database ?